# Compare 3 arrays to make a new string

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I have 3 arrays

```
array1 = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
array2 = [a,b,d,f]
array3 = [g,h]
```

How could I figure out where in array2 doesn't match array1 and then insert an element from array3?

So the output would look like

```
array4 = [a,b,g,d,h,f]


var EnglishArray = [<p>,This is a longer description. This will describe the item in greater detail.,</p>,<span please no translated Large donkey>,cat,</span>,<div>,test,<large>,<idk>,&bull;,Hello worlds,<end?>]
var HTMLTags = [<p>,</p>,<span please no translated Large donkey>,</span>,<div>,<large>,<idk>,&bull;,<end?>]
var translations = [Esta es una descripción más larga. Esto describe el tema con mayor detalle.,gato,prueba,Hola mundos]

function newString(EnglishArray, HTMLTags, translations){
  var array4 = EnglishArray;
  var j = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < EnglishArray.length; i++) {
    if(HTMLTags[i] != EnglishArray[i]){
      array4.splice(i, 1, translations[j]);
      j++;
      i++;
    }
  }
  newString = array4.join('');
  return newString;
}
```

The output it is giving me is

`<p>Esta es una descripción más larga. Esto describe el tema con mayor detalle.</p>gatocatprueba<div>Hola mundos<large>&bull;<end?>`

Instead of

```
<p>Esta es una descripción más larga. Esto describe el tema con mayor detalle.</p><span please no translated Large donkey>gato</span><div>prueba<large><idk>&bull;Hola mundos<end?>
```

When I try this on a lot smaller scale it works fine. But it seems the more tags, and translations there is more errors. After it gets too long it will start repeating the last couple words in English.

Comment: Why do your strings have no quotes? This is not valid Javascript.

Comment: They do in my code. I just didn't copy it over correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the value is included `array2` and if not take an element of `array3`.

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    array2 = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f'],
    array3 = ['g', 'h'],
    result = array1.map(v => array2.includes(v) ? v : array3.shift());
    
console.log(result);
```

Without `map` and `includes`

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
    array2 = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'f'],
    array3 = ['g', 'h'],
    result = [],
    i,
    l = array1.length;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    result.push(array2.indexOf(array1[i]) === -1 ? array3.shift() : array1[i]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This looks like it would work. The only issue I am hitting with this one is I cannot use map on the platform I'm working on

Comment: The question didn't specify whether the order of elements in the second array matters, so either of our answers should work. If you don't have `map` (how? IE below 9??) then just use a loop instead. If anything, `includes` is a *much* more recent addition.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but it destroys array2 and array3 in the process so you might want to make a copy (`array2.slice()` creates a copy, simple assignment does not).

```js
const array1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
const array2 = ['a','b','d','f']
const array3 = ['g','h']
console.log(array1.map(x => array2[0] === x ? array2.shift() : array3.shift()))
```

Comment: This looks like it would work. The only issue I am hitting with this one is I cannot use `map` on the platform I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

other solution and more readble for the people.

```
array1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
array2 = ["a","b","d","f"]
array3 = ["g","h"]

j=0;

for (i=0 ; i < array1.length ;i++){
    if (array2[i]!==array1[i])
        {
        array2.splice(i,0, array3[j]);
        j++;
        }
}

console.log(array2);`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var array1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
    var array2 = ['a','b','d','f']
    var array3 = ['g','h']
    var array4 = array1.concat(array2,array3); 
    var set = new Set(array4);
    array4 = Array.from(set);
```

Comment: You may want to add a little explanation to this code snippet, showing how exactly it works to solve the original problem.